# Removing FID as an option from ArcGIS Tool Validation Parameters

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, tools

I am currently building a script tool which requires the user to select a sorting field from a list (built using a dependency on the featureclass). This Element is working fine, but I would like to remove the FID field as an option using the ToolValidator script

I already have an element of this validation working, which enables a sub field if the sorting field is chosen and builds a filter list

```
    def updateParameters(self):

        if self.params[1].value is not None:
          self.params[2].enabled = 1
        else:
          self.params[2].enabled = 0
          self.params[2].filter.list = ['Ascending', 'Descending']
```

However I can't seem to use updateParameters() to remove the FID field from the derived list of selectable fields

```
        return
```

Comment: I think it might be useful if you were to edit your question to include more of the code you are putting together.  Sometimes seeing not just the section that you are having trouble with, but also how that section fits into the overall function will make it easier for people to suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks but the validation script really is that simple